# How to add an id to an array of object when pushing a new object into the array in node

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, findoneandupdate

I have an array called "previousEducation" which initially was empty array, but once I push an object into the array, I want each object that will be push into the array to have an object id.
Although from the screenshot I uploaded, the object id was in both (1) and (2) but I don't need the aspect where I circled in (1) I want something inform of the one I named (2) where each object will be having an id follow by the req.body. Is there a way I can push req.body into the array and archive that.

Note: the key value pair from my req.body which has been destructured to become myBody are:
exam: "waec"
subject: "english"
grade: "a1"
yera: "2023"
examNo: "com1234"
candidateNo: "waec7676"
identificationNo: "DE89392982"

Thanks.

My code.

````
  const {receivedEmail, ...myBody} = req.body 
  studentModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {email: req.body.receivedEmail},
    {$push: {previousEducation:{ _id: new ObjectId(), myBody}}}
  )
  .then((response) => {
    // console.log(response + 'JWT');
    res.send({message: 'O level Result added successfully', status: true, response});
  })
}```[![The image screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sztiw.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread your myBody Object. When you are pushing it to the array.
Add the spread operator `...myBody` like this when pushing it to the array.

```
const {receivedEmail, ...myBody} = req.body 
  studentModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {email: req.body.receivedEmail},
    {$push: {previousEducation:{ _id: new ObjectId(), ...myBody}}}
  )
  .then((response) => {
    // console.log(response + 'JWT');
    res.send({message: 'O level Result added successfully', status: true, response});
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you. Please can you also help me on how i can edit and update all the value in that array after it has been pushed using it's own _id to update it

Comment: You can use `arrayFilters` in mongodb to do this. Check the documentation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/)

Comment: I have check using the link you provided but still doesn't get it. Can I edit the code and send back

Comment: Yes you can send me the code.

Comment: I have decided to add an id instead of adding _id together with the req.body and it's doing everything I want. Thank you for the response. Till another time